# Remove a button (User Control) from a panel in C#

Tags: c#, user-controls, panel, windows-forms-designer

I have a UserControl (UC) and in that's UC I have a label and a picture box.
When I add many UC to my panel, I need to delete UC whenever user click to picture box.
But, I can't select true UC.

UC code for add event :

```
public event EventHandler<EventArgs> X_click;

private void guna2PictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (X_click != null)
    {
        X_click(guna2PictureBox1, new EventArgs());
    }
}
```

This is my code for select and delete true UC :

```
private void a1_X_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   foreach (Control item in guna2Panel1.Controls.OfType<addCatUC>())
   {
      if (sender == item)
      {
         guna2Panel1.Controls.Remove(item);
      }
   }
}
```

**Note**: I add event `a1_X_click` for all UC:

```
addC.X_click += new EventHandler<EventArgs>(a1_X_click);
```

Comment: Do you mean [UserControl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.usercontrol?view=windowsdesktop-5.0)?

Comment: yes i must to write UserControl

Comment: `guna2Panel1.Controls.Remove((addCatUC) sender);` should be sufficient. No need for the loop. You are modifying the collection that you are looping over. That will do unexpected things.

Comment: all UC are create when the app are running

Comment: and i don't know user click to which UC!!!

Comment: [pictureBox.Parent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.parent?view=windowsdesktop-5.0#System_Windows_Forms_Control_Parent) or maybe `.Parent.Parent.Parent`. We can't know. It depends how many Panels, GroupBoxes and other stuff you used.

Comment: You could try to get the correct item with something like `var item = guna2Panel1.Controls.OfType<addCatUC>().FirstOrDefault(i => i == sender)`, and then remove that item.

Comment: Why do you care about the PictureBox so much? The click event handler that you show us looks like the click event handler of a `addCatUC`, not the click handler of a PictureBox.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question. It seems we need to see *much* more code in order to help you. Before you post more code, I also suggest that you fix your naming. Use PascalCase for your class names. And give proper names to your User Controls and PictureBoxes so that we know what type they are. `a1` and ` X` are not making good names.

Comment: This is my layer orders : Form -> Panel -> UC

Comment: Did you notice: there is no PictureBox in your diagram. Form -> Panel -> UC -> ? -> PictureBox

Comment: This is my layer orders : Form -> Panel -> UC . That UC have a label and picture box

Comment: Let me ask : How can i delete parent of this sender ??

Answer (score 0):

I used this code and was able to remove the correct button:

```
    private void a1_X_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ((Control)sender).Parent.Dispose();
    }
```

Comment: If you need to raise that event (maybe you need information from that UserControl before it is disposed of?), then: `X_click((Control)sender).Parent, new EventArgs());`

Comment: @HansPassant: I definitely learned something by your edit. It's a bit sad that the description of Control.Dispose or Component.Dispose does not mention that the control will remove itself from the list of controls it is in. I always removed it myself. I was assuming that some other code that iterates that list would access it and get an ObjectDisposedException.